# 'X Error of failed request: BadRequest' when using nvidia driver with video acceleration (VA)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I'd like to simply show a testsource using gstreamer-1.0.
When I use (I guess) non-accelerated output `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! xvimagesink` everything works find, but when I try to play it like `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink` I get the following error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
libva info: VA-API version 0.35.0
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (DRI2)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  1 (DRI2Connect)
  Serial number of failed request:  15
  Current serial number in output stream:  15
```

I've installed `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.44.run` on `Ubuntu 14.04.5` as follows:

1. Remove old drivers: `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`
2. Blacklist the old driver by the run script (It asks you to do so, quit after it)
3. Reboot
4. Stop the services: `service lightdm stop && service x11-common stop`
5. Install the driver: `./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.44.run --no-x-check`
6. Installed VA stuff concerning https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Video-Dekodierung_beschleunigen/: `sudo apt-get install libvdpau1 vdpauinfo vdpau-va-driver vainfo`
7. Reboot

Here are some helpful outputs, which still deliver errors:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA -A2 
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 [GeForce GTX 660] [10de:11c0] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:354e]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia

$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 0.35.0
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (DRI2)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  1 (DRI2Connect)
  Serial number of failed request:  11
  Current serial number in output stream:  11

$ glxinfo 
name of display: localhost:10.0
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  20

$ uname -a
Linux alpia 4.4.0-38-generic #57~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 17:20:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep driver
[   127.579] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[   127.579]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[   127.786] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[   128.733] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[   128.815]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 22.1
[   128.815] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[   128.830] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[   128.831] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   128.831] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   128.831] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   128.831] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   128.832] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   128.832] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   128.832] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   128.832] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   128.832] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   128.832] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   128.833] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   128.833] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   128.833] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard'
[   128.833] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'USB Optical Mouse'
[   128.834] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
```

Does anybody have a hint?
I know that it worked once with this PC following the instructions, but now something seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by reverting everything to stock ubuntu, but video acceleration does still not work:

1. Remove former driver: `sudo  ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-xxx.xx.run --uninstall`
2. **uninstalling** which was related to nvidia (search related packages by `dpkg -l`): nvidia, cuda, primus, vdpau-va-driver, vainfo, libvdpau1, vdpauinfo
3. Remove all blacklist stuff for the nouveau drivers: Remove necessary files in `/etc/modprobe.d`
4. Revert xconfig by: `sudo X -configure && sudo cp xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
5. Reinstall `mesa-vdpau-drivers-lts-<your release>`
6. **IMPORTANT**: Remove the gstreamer vaapi, so that it does not try to use the acceleration when plugins like `autoconvert`or `autovideosink` are used: `sudo apt-get remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi gstreamer1.0-vaapi-doc libgstreamer-vaapi1.0-0:amd64 libgstreamer-vaapi1.0-dev`

Now, the test programs `glxinfo` and `glxgears` work again as expected.

**Anyway: The unsuccessful try**: I still do not know why the VA stuff does not work with the original driver even when using the official ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-suggests nvidia-340
```

`glxinfo` and `glxgears` works, but `vainfo` and `vdpauinfo` still output errors.
I managed `vdpauinfo` to output something other than an error by using the `mesa` drivers and exporting (If the variables point to the proprietary driver, it wont work):

```
export VDPAU_DRIVER_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/
export VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl
```

But this is just the display driver, right. So I need to tell VA API, that it has to use `vdpau` like this (?):

```
export LIBVA_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/
export LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=vdpau
```

But in that case, `vainfo` only replies with errors, no matter which driver name I chose.

**If anyone knows how to make it work, please help.**
But for now, gstreamer works again (but with high CPU load).

Here are some Links:

```
VDPAU Library Layout: http://http.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/vdpau/doxygen/html/group__api__winsys__x11.html
NVIDIA driver archive: http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html
Hardware video acceleration (Arch): https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hardware_video_acceleration
NVIDIA xorg config: http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/331.20/README/editxconfig.html
```